# BeginDelayedTransition is not smooth when applied to recyclerview

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, transition

I am trying to animate my RecyclerView bounds when content is updated with a [delayedTransition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html) but the animation is not smooth.

This is what I currently get :

```html
<iframe src="//giphy.com/embed/wd8CN7qJUuWpq" width="480" height="270" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/wd8CN7qJUuWpq">via GIPHY</a></p>
```

This is what I want to achieve :

```html
<iframe src="//giphy.com/embed/WmHEhqhPTr7Tq" width="480" height="270" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/WmHEhqhPTr7Tq">via GIPHY</a></p>
```

Any idea how to get the smooth animation ?

Comment: Ever got a solution for this?

Comment: No, I ended up calculating the bottomSheet size before expanding it.